# List tables that are made by the user/developer and not by SQLite itself

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

If I run the following command:

```
select * from sqlite_master where type = \'table\';
```

I get the tables I created, but also tables like: `android_metadata` and `sqlite_sequence`. I would like to have a function in my app what wipes the content of my tables but I rather not touch the tables the database created for itself.

I list all tables, extract their name, filter the list and call a `delete from $tablename` on the list:

```
  Future<List<QueryRow>> _getNumberOfExistingTableRows() async {
    List<String> sqliteTableNames = ["android_metadata", "sqlite_sequence"];
    String selectTablesSql = "select * from sqlite_master where type = \'table\';";
    final result = await customWriteReturning(selectTablesSql);
    result.removeWhere((row) => sqliteTableNames.contains(row.data["name"]));
    return result;
  }

   List<String> tableNameList = _queryRowsToTableNames(await _getNumberOfExistingTableRows());
    for (String tableName in tableNameList) {
      await customStatement("delete from $tableName;");
    }
```

It works, but if SQLite in a future version creates another table for itself, this would wipe that table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%' AND name NOT LIKE 'android_%';`
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Is there any rule that sqlite team won't make their own table that is not started with `android` or `sqlite`?

Comment: @stacktrace2234  `sqlite_` is reserved and results in *object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_mytable*. The rule is that only sqlite can create tables that start with `sqlite_`, thus should system tables be introduced then they would very likely start with sqlite_. SQLite do not govern the android implementation, rather android_metadata was introduced by those who developed the android SQLite API. Of course if you want to protect against "other tables" then you could introduce your own table naming rule/convention.